# R Programming Newbie! - Median Loop Function Broken

Tags: r, function, loops, median

So the function below is using a really big dataframe.  Two columns of this DF are the year houses were built and the other is the cost.

I want to input the column name, in this case ds$Built as the function argument

YearCount <- the length of the number of unique values, years, in DS$Built

YearList <-  a vector of the unique values, years, in ds$Built

Then I want it to do a for loop of YearCount number of iterations where it takes the median of values in Cost06 but only where the values in ds$Built = the value in YearList[i]

Take the resulting median and append it to the empty vector CostVec

At the end, make a 2 column dataframe of YearList and iMedian.

---

But this does not work. It is doing what you see below where it is assigning the same median value (the value from the last iteration in the loop) to all the years, rather than making each year's result available.

I'm a newbie so please thank you very much for your patience.

```
Median.DF <- function(x)
      {                 
            YearCount <- length(unique(x))
            YearList <- unique(x)
            CostVec <- c()
            for (i in YearCount) {
                  imedian <- median(ds[x == YearList,"COST06"],na.rm = TRUE)
                  CostVec <- append(CostVec,imedian)
                  }
            MedianCost.data <- data.frame(YearList, CostVec)
            return(MedianCost.data)
      }

  YearList CostVec
1      2004    1629
2      2007    1629
3      2005    1629
4      1980    1629
5      1985    1629
6      2003    1629
7      2008    1629
8      1990    1629
9      1975    1629
10     1970    1629
11     1950    1629
12     1920    1629
13     1960    1629
14     1930    1629
15     1919    1629
16     1940    1629
17     1995    1629
18     2006    1629
19     2009    1629
20     2000    1629
21     2002    1629
22     2001    1629
23     2010    1629
24     2011    1629
25     2012    1629
26     2013    1629
```

Comment: Did you mean to make all the values in costVec be the same?  Also in your example,  all years are different.  That does not provide a very interesting test case.

Comment: @Mitsugi, welcome to SO! Make sure you accept answers to close the question, so that people know this one has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better (cleaner, more R-like) way to do this. I'll leave it to you to turn it into the function.

```
df <- data.frame(YearList=sample(2000:2006,30, replace=T), CostVec=10^3+100*runif(30,0,1))
dfSplit <- split(df, df$YearList)
medianByYears <- lapply(dfSplit, function(x) median(x$CostVec))
medianByYearsClean <- do.call(rbind, medianByYears)
data.frame(Years=rownames(medianByYearsClean), MedianPrices=medianByYearsClean, row.names=NULL)
```

A few other tips:

Before you write a function, just test each line by line outside of a function. The main problem here is:

```
for (i in YearCount) { do stuff }
```

is analogous to

```
for (i in 5){print(i)}
```

Which does one thing once. You want to do:

```
for (i in seq(YearCount)) { do stuff }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am coming from VBA scripting in Excel so I need to work on changing how I think.  I will look at what you did above and see how I can make it work well.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mitsugi, great, I came from a similar path. Keep reworking your methods and you'll find it pays off. On SO, it's important the workflow of the community to close questions once they've been answered - please tick the check next to the 0 on my answer to help other answerers.